# How to retrieve JSON data from a url and show them in a list view in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I use the following URL for calling JSON data to my windows phone application.

http://rdeshapriya.com/vnotifications/webService.php?action=getLeaveNotifications

But I can't call the JSON objects in the URL and view the data in a Listbox in Windows phone 7.1 application. Please help me.

Comment: Any code that you have tried to make it possible? Please sahre some more code on what actually has been done by you, till now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the json file and parse.
When you have data you can fill a list on WP